# Not able to use pivot function in oracle sql develope

Tags: sql, oracle

this is the table which I need to pivot(age range must be an attribute and percentage as its row)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyQpV.jpg

**already coded:**

```
SELECT SECOND_RESPONSE, 25-30, 30-35, 18-25, 45-50, 40-45, 35-40, 55-60 FROM
(SELECT SECOND_RESPONSE FROM SEC_ANALYSIS_AGE)
PIVOT
(
MAX(PERCENTAGE) FOR FIRST_RESPONSE IN (25-30, 30-35, 18-25, 45-50, 40-45, 35-40, 55-60)
) AS PIV;
```

**Output**

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 24 Column: 3

Comment: Please post your sample data and expected output as text.

Comment: thanks but got the answer @AnkitBajpai

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an include `FIRST_RESPONSE`, `PERCENTAGE` columns select statement. Would be this one:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT SECOND_RESPONSE, FIRST_RESPONSE, PERCENTAGE FROM SEC_ANALYSIS_AGE)
PIVOT
(
MAX(PERCENTAGE) FOR FIRST_RESPONSE IN ('25-30' as "25-30", '30-35' as "30-35", '18-25' as "18-25", '45-50' as "45-50", '40-45' as "40-45", '35-40' as "35-40", '55-60' as "55-60")
)
```

thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).